# Writes on Cassandra Network Partitioned Nodes

Tags: cassandra, high-availability, distributed-system, consistency, network-partitioning

Setup:

A Single Cassandra Cluster with many many nodes. There are many tokens and many nodes. These tokens are partitioned onto these nodes. Let us take a token which is partitioned on 5 nodes.

- There are 5 nodes for a token.
- Now among these 5 nodes, 4 nodes get network partitioned from the rest of the cluster
- Now some clients issuing writes will be having the entry for these 4 nodes, so in this way we will be able to make that write happen among these 4 non-available nodes.

Does Cassandra Ensure that the writes does not happen on these 4 nodes which are network partitioned ?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear."  I don't see a question mark "?" anywhere, so it's hard to know what the actual question is.  Also, what you mean by "network partitioned?"  Do you mean some nodes within the same logical datacenter are on different networks?  Or that they are unreachable?

Comment: Edited the question @Aaron. Hope this clears the doubts. By network partitioned i mean those nodes are unreachable from the rest of the group of the cassandra nodes.

Comment: when you say "Let us take a token which is partitioned on 5 nodes"..what does that mean ? As per my understanding a single token belongs to single node and its replication..are you trying to say same thing ?